# How to enable pinch & zoom on mobile?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

We use tempera template.
Is it possible to enable pinch and zoom on this template for mobile devices?
If not is it possible to do a workaround, or use another template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the zoom thing is enabled by default, to disable it people add a meta tag in the template, I'm not a frontend developer but i believe it looks something like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Try commenting/removing that line from your template and experiment with it.

Comment: what if pinch and zoom does not work even without that line?

Comment: Hi @Fandango68, as I mentioned above I'm not really a frontend developer, so I can't help you debug this issue, you might want to create a new question and hopefully someone else can help you.